# How do you modify a table cell depending on its column type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I want to update cells in an SQL table depending on the type of its column. More specifically, I want to replace NULL values by either '',0,0.0 or '1900-01-01' depending on the column type. The table has 60 columns and so a manual approach is awkward.

The approach I have tried uses metadata and I want to generate an update script.

Use case is for an import into Excel where the NULL values must be taken care off in a column type dependant way.

Comment: You  need to create dynamic sql with use of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: It's worth noting that all numeric types and `DATETIME` (but not the newer date/time types) accept an implicitly converted `0` as a value. This potentially simplifies the approach.

Comment: For a lot of datatypes, actually setting the value to `''` would work for your requirement. Only `varbinary`, and `decimal` generated an error when testing. [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af8d9c4d0fcca323c94c6b4e236850c3)

Comment: It's really bad that they actually allowed `''` to convert to a `DATE` of `1900-01-01`. They went to the trouble of disallowing `0` explicitly, but converting the empty string to what is not even the smallest value the type supports was apparently good for compatibility. Even so, that does make `''` the "best" choice for these kinds of hacks (for some value of "best").

Comment: I don't disagree @JeroenMostert. I'm really not sure why they "removed" the numeric to date(time) conversion for the new datatypes. Interestingly as well, although implicit conversion of `''` to a `varbinary` is not allowed, explicit *is*. So that just leaves `decimal`/`numeric`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to check `float` and `money`, but they allow implicit conversion too. [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18da4a57443c1cdcf1176fa3fe2b6f40)

Comment: Explicit conversion makes sense, because you can meaningfully convert any `[N][VAR]CHAR` value to a `VARBINARY`, getting its code points. The empty string converts to an empty `VARBINARY` there. (Why implicit conversion was then disallowed is not as clear, but it's arguably a good thing nonetheless.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS colname, DATA_TYPE AS coltype
INTO #result_columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable';


WITH cte(colname, default_value) AS (

SELECT colname,

    CASE
        WHEN coltype IN ('varchar','nvarchar') THEN ''''''
        WHEN coltype IN ('int','money') THEN '0'
        WHEN coltype IN ('date') THEN '''1900-01-01'''
        WHEN coltype IN ('float') THEN '0.0'
    END AS default_value
FROM #result_columns

) 
SELECT 'UPDATE mytable SET ' + colname + '=' + default_value + ' WHERE ' + colname + ' IS NULL;' 

FROM cte;
```

-- result :

```
UPDATE mytable SET Caracteristique='' WHERE Caracteristique IS NULL;
UPDATE mytable SET Couleur='' WHERE Couleur IS NULL;
UPDATE mytable SET Forme='' WHERE Forme IS NULL;
UPDATE mytable SET Machine='' WHERE Machine IS NULL;
UPDATE mytable SET QteChargee=0.0 WHERE QteChargee IS NULL;
```

Comment: Is that the answer? Or should it have been an edit to your question?

Comment: And at least format your code and add an explanation of why it (doesn't) work(s).

Comment: Also, this will fail as soon as you have a column with that starts with a numerical character, has a space, or certain special characters. You *could* also inject into it, if you have permissions to change the columns within a table, such as renaming them or adding a new column..

Comment: Yes, that's my answer.

Comment: Then, like i comment, you might want to give it some context, as a question with a random, unexplained, answer doesn't help anyone. Out of interest, why did you choose to update every column separately? This will mean a statement for every column (of which you said there are 60), which means 60 `UPDATE` statements; which would be far more costly that a single one.

Comment: It is simply a way of generating the 60 update lines, instead of writting them by hand which would be too error prone. Then you could use STRING_AGG() to merge the 60 update lines into a single script and execute it.

Comment: It is a way to generate a script which would have been error prone to write by hand

Comment: What my user ultimately wanted to do was a csv export, and a subsequent import of the csv into excel. The NULL values had to be replaced by 0, or 'empty string', or '1900-01-01', ... according to the type of the column the NULL value was in.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the easiest way seems to be use `''`. The only exception (I found) was for `decimal`/`numeric`, where implicit and explicit conversion is not allowed.

As shown below, you can write the statement out (but I exclude the `decimal` column) or do it dynamically:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                        SomeInt int,
                        SomeDecimal decimal(10,2),
                        SomeFloat float,
                        SomeMoney money,
                        SomeDate date,
                        SomeDatetime datetime,
                        SomeTime time,
                        SomeDatetime2 datetime2(1),
                        SomeVarbinary varbinary(12),
                        SomeVarchar varchar(10),
                        SomeBit bit);
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (SomeInt,
                           SomeDecimal,
                           SomeFloat,
                           SomeMoney,
                           SomeDate,
                           SomeDatetime,
                           SomeTime,
                           SomeDatetime2,
                           SomeVarbinary,
                           SomeVarchar,
                           SomeBit)
VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
      (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
GO
UPDATE dbo.TestTable
SET SomeInt = ISNULL(SomeInt,''),
    --SomeDecimal = ISNULL(SomeDecimal,''),
    SomeFloat = ISNULL(SomeFloat,''),
    SomeMoney = ISNULL(SomeMoney,''),
    SomeDate = ISNULL(SomeDate,''),
    SomeDatetime = ISNULL(SomeDatetime,''),
    SomeTime = ISNULL(SomeTime,''),
    SomeDatetime2 = ISNULL(SomeDatetime2,''),
    SomeVarbinary = ISNULL(SomeVarbinary,CONVERT(varbinary,'')),
    SomeVarchar = ISNULL(SomeVarchar,''),
    SomeBit = ISNULL(SomeBit,'')
WHERE ID = 1;
GO
DECLARE @Schema sysname = N'dbo',
        @Table sysname = N'TestTable';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'SET ' + STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
                                   N'    ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + N' = ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + N',' + CASE C.DATA_TYPE WHEN N'decimal' THEN '0)'
                                                                                                                                           WHEN N'numeric' THEN '0)'
                                                                                                                                           ELSE N'CONVERT(' + QUOTENAME(C.DATA_TYPE) + N',N''''))'
                                                                                 END
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                            WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
                              AND C.TABLE_NAME = @Table
                              AND C.COLUMN_NAME != 'ID' --You'll need a better method to ignore your ID column
                            FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,7,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
          N'WHERE ID = 2;'; --you won't want this if you're doing every row.

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TestTable;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=161b709859fd962467c8e14ac17dcc8f)

If you're using SQL Server 2017+, you can simplify the above by using `STRING_AGG` instead of `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` to create a "delimited" list of the columns in the table.

Comment: my table has 60 columns, as written in the description. That's why I want to avoid this approach.

Comment: What approach @user3046585 the literal or Dynamic one? The literal one was an example of the simplicity required. The Dynamic one won't have an issue with 100's of columns, let alone just 60. If you don't want to use a dynamic solution, why does your answer use a dynamic solution too?

Comment: my table has 60 columns, so the literal one is too bulky and above all error prone. I want to generate a script from the metadata and execute it without going to the trouble of writing the 60 lines myself. So, yes I want to use a dynamic solution. That's what this post is all about.

Comment: And this answer has a dynamic solution @user3046585 . Unlike yours, however, it won't suffer from a failure with a column that must be delimit identified, and can't suffer injection. it also runs one `UPDATE` for the whole table, not 1 per column; which be far faster. The example does limit the rows in the `WHERE`, but that was to show the difference in solutions.

Comment: Your answer is pretty much the same as mine.